# How to connect a horizontal/vertical line between two divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering how to connect two div elements with a line which is even distanced kind of like the one in this website:
[image: Grok Learning]

```
JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/mcbvb8m2/
```

How would you do this for horizontal and vertical divs?
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Use an image editor software. That's all that I can say if you share only an image and no code.

Comment: I can't really link to the page as it's on my account...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a div with a class of something like `connector` and style this to look like the connector with the following CSS:

```
.connector {
  border: 6px solid #333;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  height:50px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

You can change the appearance of this by playing around with the border thickness, colour and border-radius.  This takes care of the styling.

To position it correctly, you can use absolute or relative positioning.  In this case to use absolute positioning, apply `position:absolute`to the `connector` class.  To position it use properties such as `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right`. The absolute position will absolutely position the element relative to the entire page so I'd recommend adding `position:relative` to its parent container so it is positioned relative to this.

```css
.container{
 height:800px;
 width:100%;
 padding:50px;
background:#eeeeee;
    position:relative;
  }

.box-1{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background:blue;
  color:#fff;
  margin-bottom:30px;
 }

.box-2{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
 }

.connector {
  position:absolute;
  top: 335px;
  left: 35px;
  border: 6px solid #333;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  height:50px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="box-1">
    Box 1
  </div>
  
  <div class="box-2">
    Box 2
  </div>
  
  <div class="connector"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: What happens if I want to have a paragraph or two in between? Then the content pushes the box downward so the connector is connected to nothing

Comment: I mean, I can set the paragraph to have a line height of 15px and font size 15px and then change the height of the connector to 30px more (because my paragraph had two lines, so 15*2), but is there an easier method?

Comment: You could add the position:relative to one of the boxes instead and place the connector inside the box.  This would absolutely position the connector within this.  You could then position it to the bottom(or top) and so long as the gap between the two boxes doesn't change, it should stay connected to the other box.